# How to convert a list of words into multiple sentences in python

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, stanford-nlp, allennlp, nlp-question-answering

Eg:
Input:
Name: ['FirstName','LastName','FirstNameLastName']
Customer Account Number: ['Customer', 'Account', 'Number', 'Customer Account', 'Customer Number', 'Customer Account Number']
output:
FirstNameLastName
Customer Account Number

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a defined pattern to the arrays like:

index 0: first name
index 1: last name
index 2: fullName

to the first array, and something like it to the second. You can just add the strings together to the output.

There are some ways to do it, using python, usually you'll prefer to use fstrings.

On the exemple you settled would be like this:

```
output = f'{name[2]} {customer_account_number[5]}'
```